# PHP Warning: Illegal string offset

Tags: php, string, offset

I am newbie in PHP.
A PHP was migrated today from 5.3.3 to 5.4.4 version (Debian Squeeze to Debian Wheezy) and, after this, I get this error from Apache log :

**> PHP Warning:  Illegal string offset 'phptype' in xyz**

The line is:

```
self::$conn[$dsn['phptype']] = $mdb2;
```

I need help to restore the system.

Comment: I guess either `self::$conn` or `$dsn` is a string.

Comment: `var_dump(self::$conn, $dsn)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Illegal string offset Warning PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9869150/illegal-string-offset-warning-php)

Answer (score 4):

```
<?php
$a = 'Hello';
echo $a['whatever'];
?>
```

As some of the guys in the comments are saying, doing something like this would probably cause that error. As you can see in the example above `$a` is a string rather than an array. This means that you cannot access it with a key (if however you wanted to get the 3rd letter in the string it would be ok to do `$a[2]`).

You need to check that `self::$conn` and `$dsn` are actually arrays rather than strings. As  Álvaro G. Vicario says in the comments, you can do this by dumping the variable:

`var_dump(self::$conn, $dsn)`

Answer (score 0):

Illegal offset type errors occur when you attempt to access an array index using an object or an array as the index key. Check whether your array is proper.