# Illegal string offset 'background-color' dynamic.css.php

Tags: css, string, wordpress

New!

ok i deleted the bg options but now i get error from the font-family..

```
Warning: Illegal string offset 'font-family' in .../wp-content/themes/curves/includes/custom-css.php on line 20

Warning: Illegal string offset 'font-family' in .../wp-content/themes/curves/includes/custom-css.php on line 26

Warning: Illegal string offset 'font-family' in .../wp-content/themes/curves/includes/custom-css.php on line 31

Warning: Illegal string offset 'font-family' in .../wp-content/themes/curves/includes/custom-css.php on line 37

Warning: Illegal string offset 'font-family' in .../wp-content/themes/curves/includes/custom-css.php on line 42

Warning: Illegal string offset 'font-family' in .../wp-content/themes/curves/includes/custom-css.php on line 47

Warning: Illegal string offset 'font-family' in ..../wp-content/themes/curves/includes/custom-css.php on line 56
```

i think this is not writen well

```
$h1_font = ot_get_option( 'h1_font', 'lato' );

$custom_css = "
h1 { 
    font-family: ". $h1_font['font-family'] .";
    font-size: ". ot_get_option( 'h1_size', '24' ). "px;
    font-weight: 300;
}
```

any help? thx

---

Have some issues with PHP 5.4.. I have a friend who wrote the code for me because i only design and now the guy is unreachable and.. here i am :)

So I have a `customcss.php` who creates a `dynamic.css` for a Wordpress theme. 
I have installed the theme on host gator which has PHP 5.4 and i get this warnings:

```
Warning: Illegal string offset 'font-family' in /.../public_html/aaa/wp-       content/themes/curves/includes/custom-css.php on line 60

Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 0 in /.../public_html/aaa/wp-content/themes/curves/includes/custom-css.php on line 20

Warning: Illegal string offset 'background-color' in /home4/mthemes/public_html/aaa/wp-content/themes/curves/includes/custom-css.php on line 60

Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 0 in /.../public_html/aaa/wp-content/themes/curves/includes/custom-css.php on line 60

Warning: Illegal string offset 'background-repeat' in /.../public_html/aaa/wp-content/themes/curves/includes/custom-css.php on line 63

Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 0 in /.../public_html/aaa/wp-content/themes/curves/includes/custom-css.php on line 63

Warning: Illegal string offset 'background-attachment' in /.../public_html/aaa/wp-content/themes/curves/includes/custom-css.php on line 67
```

etc..

```
<?php
//custom inline css
function curves_style_custom() {
 wp_enqueue_style(
  'custom-style',
  get_template_directory_uri() . '/dynamic.css'
 );

$h1_font = ot_get_option( 'h1_font', 'lato' );
$h2_font = ot_get_option( 'h2_font', 'lato' );
$h3_font = ot_get_option( 'h3_font', 'lato' );
$h4_font = ot_get_option( 'h4_font', 'lato' );
$h5_font = ot_get_option( 'h5_font', 'lato' );
$h6_font = ot_get_option( 'h6_font', 'lato' );
$g_font = ot_get_option( 'g_font', 'lato' );


$custom_css = "
h1 { 
    font-family: ". $h1_font['font-family'] .";
    font-size: ". ot_get_option( 'h1_size', '24' ). "px;
    font-weight: 300;
}

h2 {     
    font-family: ". $h2_font['font-family'] .";
    font-size: ". ot_get_option( 'h2_size', '22' ) ."px;
    font-weight: 300;
}

h3 { 
    font-family: ". $h3_font['font-family'] .";
    font-size:". ot_get_option( 'h3_size', '18' ) ."px;
    font-weight: 300;

}

h4 { 
    font-family: ". $h4_font['font-family'] .";
    font-size: ". ot_get_option( 'h4_size', '16' ) ."px;
    font-weight: 300;
}
h5 { 
    font-family: ". $h5_font['font-family'] .";
    font-size: ". ot_get_option( 'h5_size', '12' ) ."px;
    font-weight: 300;
}

h6 { 
    font-family: ". $h6_font['font-family'] .";
    font-size: ". ot_get_option( 'h6_size', '10' ) ."px;
    font-weight: 300;
}   

p  { 
    font-size: ". ot_get_option( 'p_size', '14' ) ."px;
}

body{
    font-family: ". $g_font['font-family'] .";
";
$body_bg = ot_get_option( 'body_bg_image' );

if($body_bg['background-color'] != ""){
    $custom_css .= 'background-color: '. $body_bg['background-color'] .';';
} 
if($body_bg['background-repeat'] != ""){
    $custom_css .= 'background-repeat: '. $body_bg['background-repeat'] .';';
}

if($body_bg['background-attachment'] != ""){
    $custom_css .= 'background-attachment: '. $body_bg['background-attachment'] .';';
}

if($body_bg['background-position'] != ""){
    $custom_css .= 'background-position: '. $body_bg['background-position'] .';';
}

if($body_bg['background-size'] != ""){
    $custom_css .= 'background-size: '. $body_bg['background-size'] .';';
}

if($body_bg['background-image'] != ""){
    $custom_css .= 'background-image: url("'. $body_bg['background-image'] .'");';
}

$custom_css .= "}";
```

This code applies the option selected in admin (option tree) in an inline css.

In PHP 5.3 it works but in PHP 5.4 it shows the warning.

Also I discovered that this happens because, when I first install the theme, there are no option like `font-family` selected in option tree although as you ca see I set a default value.

Comment: ...and what exactly the `enter code here$custom_css` means, at very bottom of your code??

Comment: sorry wrong copy paste. it`s only $custom_css .= "}";

Comment: possible duplicate of [Illegal string offset Warning PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9869150/illegal-string-offset-warning-php)

Answer (score 1):

Before you use an array member, you should first check, if it is set via e.g.:

```
if(isset($body_bg['background-image'])) {
    // do something with it
}
```

See also the answers in [Illegal string offset Warning PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9869150/illegal-string-offset-warning-php)

For example you could do the following:

```
$h1_font = ot_get_option( 'h1_font', 'lato' );

$h1_font_family = "sans-serif";
if(isset($h1_font['font-family']))
    $h1_font_family = $h1_font['font-family'];

$custom_css = "
h1 { 
    font-family: ". $h1_font_family .";
    font-size: ". ot_get_option( 'h1_size', '24' ). "px;
    font-weight: 300;
}
```

And so on for all the styles you want do define. You are providing a default value (`"sans-serif"`) and if the setting `'font-family'` is available in your option, it replaces the default value.

Comment: thx for quickreply but i dindt mention that i dont know php :(

Comment: it could be a lot a help if you cand show me exactly how the code should look like

Comment: I've added an example, does that help?