# Illegal string offset 'type' in extra.class.php on line 32

Tags: php, wordpress

I am having following errors on my [website](http://softwarefails.com/); I am very new to WordPress not able to track issue.

```
Warning: Illegal string offset 'type' in /home/content/p3pnexwpnas03_data02/52/2259652/html/wp-content/themes/softwarefails/lib/php/extra.class.php on line 32

Warning: Illegal string offset 'type' in /home/content/p3pnexwpnas03_data02/52/2259652/html/wp-content/themes/softwarefails/lib/php/extra.class.php on line 32
```

**extra.class.php**

[Code in fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c8cy7prf/)

Error is all over the website, I am not able to upload any images it gives following error.

```
An error occurred in the upload. Please try again later.
```

Comment: you can't run php at jsfiddle, you could use an alternative that supports php, like ideone.com

Comment: @JimL I know that I have added code as it was too lengthy to add here. it was exceeding 30k stack limit.

Answer (score 0):

`$inputs['type']` probably doesn't exist test first if it exist before doing a string compare

Comment: can you please be more specific and elaborate it as I am new to it.

Comment: How are you calling  this function  get_attachment_struct( $inputs )

Answer (score 0):

This error is cause when you are trating the string as a full array.  For eg

```
$fruit_counts = array('apples'=>2, 'oranges'=>5, 'pears'=>0);
echo $fruit_counts['oranges']; // echoes 5
$fruit_counts = "an unexpected string assignment";


echo $fruit_counts['oranges']; // causes illegal string offset error
```

Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9869150/illegal-string-offset-warning-php) too