# Warning: Illegal string offset 'cur_name'

Tags: php

I am getting the error "Warning: Illegal string offset 'cur_name'" I am just learning php and not sure how to fix this error, any help would be appreciated.

```
$amount=mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("select sum(amount) from transactions where  adv_id=".$rs_query["id"]." group by adv_id"));
            if($amount)
            {
            echo $cur["cur_name"].$amount[0];
            ?>
```

Comment: Where do you declare `$cur`? Also, you didn't close your if branch. And: mysql_* functions are deprecated. See the warning on http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php.

Comment: See, for example, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9869150/illegal-string-offset-warning-php or any of the other "related questions" in the lower right portion of this page.

Answer (score 0):

try this way:

```
        if($amount)

        echo $amount[0];
```

but you should better use PDO not `mysql_fetch_array` that is deprecated, and read more all over internet :-)