# PHP "Illegal string offset" error when looping through array

Tags: php, arrays

I am using the Amazon API to get some XML data, which is then passed through the json_decode() function.

Here are two samples of the data that is returned:

```
[BrowseNodes] => Array
    (
        [Request] => Array
            (
                [IsValid] => True
                [BrowseNodeLookupRequest] => Array
                    (
                        [BrowseNodeId] => 2645269011
                        [ResponseGroup] => BrowseNodeInfo
                    )

            )

        [BrowseNode] => Array
            (
                [BrowseNodeId] => 2645269011
                [Name] => Featured Categories
                [Children] => Array
                    (
                        [BrowseNode] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => Array
                                    (
                                        [BrowseNodeId] => 3741261
                                        [Name] => Cooktops
                                    )

                                [1] => Array
                                    (
                                        [BrowseNodeId] => 3741271
                                        [Name] => Dishwashers
                                    )

                                [2] => Array
                                    (
                                        [BrowseNodeId] => 3741331
                                        [Name] => Freezers
                                    )

                                [3] => Array
                                    (
                                        [BrowseNodeId] => 2399939011
                                        [Name] => Ice Makers
                                    )

                            )

                    )
```

and

```
[BrowseNodes] => Array
    (
        [Request] => Array
            (
                [IsValid] => True
                [BrowseNodeLookupRequest] => Array
                    (
                        [BrowseNodeId] => 3774781
                        [ResponseGroup] => BrowseNodeInfo
                    )

            )

        [BrowseNode] => Array
            (
                [BrowseNodeId] => 3774781
                [Name] => Vitamin D
                [Children] => Array
                    (
                        [BrowseNode] => Array
                            (
                                [BrowseNodeId] => 6936848011
                                [Name] => D3
                            )

                    )
```

I am then using this code to obtain data for each of the children:

```
if(isset($result['BrowseNodes']['BrowseNode']['Children'])){
$childs = $result['BrowseNodes']['BrowseNode']['Children']['BrowseNode'];
        foreach($childs as $child){
            $browsenodeid = $child['BrowseNodeId'];
            $name = $child['Name'];
        }
    }
```

Everything works fine in the first sample, but in the second one, I am getting the following errors:

**Warning: Illegal string offset 'BrowseNodeId'**

**Warning: Illegal string offset 'Name'**

If I echo $browsenodeid and $name in the second example, it gives me 6 and D as the output.

Any ideas as to what I am doing wrong? I am quite confused; to me the data I am looping through in both cases seems to be the same, the only difference being that in the first case, the array has 4 elements and in the second it has 1 element.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try a var_dump($childs); instead of foreach() to test what contains this variable

Answer (score 0):

The reason I think is that in case 1: the structure is `[BrowseNode][0][BrowseNodeId]` whereas in case 2 it is : `[BrowseNode][BrowseNodeId]` that `[0]` is missing , you can fix it in the data.

Read more at: [Illegal string offset Warning PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9869150/illegal-string-offset-warning-php)