# Illegal string offset in insert batch codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, codeigniter

I want to insert batch in codeigniter based multiple upload.
This is result from :

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($this->upload->data());
```

Array :

```
Array
(
[file_name] => EOLU_111111115450530.jpg
[file_type] => image/jpeg
[file_path] => C:/xampp/htdocs/depo/assets/uploads/EOLU 11111111545053/
[full_path] => C:/xampp/htdocs/depo/assets/uploads/EOLU 11111111545053/EOLU_111111115450530.jpg
[raw_name] => EOLU_111111115450530
[orig_name] => EOLU_111111115450530.jpg
[client_name] => Archana_Sastry_bollywood_celebrity_actress_model_girl_beautiful_indian_brunette_pretty_cute_beauty_face_lips_eyes_hair_sexy_pose_smile_2560x1600.jpg
[file_ext] => .jpg
[file_size] => 201.36
[is_image] => 1
[image_width] => 2560
[image_height] => 1600
[image_type] => jpeg
[image_size_str] => width="2560" height="1600"
)

Array
(
[file_name] => EOLU_111111115450531.jpg
[file_type] => image/jpeg
[file_path] => C:/xampp/htdocs/depo/assets/uploads/EOLU 11111111545053/
[full_path] => C:/xampp/htdocs/depo/assets/uploads/EOLU 11111111545053/EOLU_111111115450531.jpg
[raw_name] => EOLU_111111115450531
[orig_name] => EOLU_111111115450531.jpg
[client_name] => art_lara_croft_girl_spray_background_suit_women_females_girls_sexy_babes_1920x1200.jpg
[file_ext] => .jpg
[file_size] => 306.69
[is_image] => 1
[image_width] => 1920
[image_height] => 1200
[image_type] => jpeg
[image_size_str] => width="1920" height="1200"
)
```

This is the **Model**

```
function save_files_info($files) {
    //start db traction
    $this->db->trans_start();
    //file data
    $file_data = array();
    foreach ($files as $file) {
        $file_data[] = array(
            "file_name" => $file['file_name'],
            "file_orig_name" => $file['orig_name'],
            "file_path" => $file['full_path']
        );
    };
    //insert file data
    $this->db->insert_batch($this->file, $file_data);
    //complete the transaction
    $this->db->trans_complete();
    //check transaction status
    if ($this->db->trans_status() === FALSE) {
        foreach ($files as $file) {
            $file_path = $file['full_path'];
            //delete the file from destination
            if (file_exists($file_path)) {
                unlink($file_path);
            }
        }
        //rollback transaction
        $this->db->trans_rollback();
        return FALSE;
    } else {
        //commit the transaction
        $this->db->trans_commit();
        return TRUE;
    }
}
```

I got this error :

```
 Severity: Warning

 Message:  Illegal string offset 'file_name'

 Filename: models/m_surveyor.php

 Line Number: 141
```

This is my table :

```
mysql> desc tb_files;
+----------------+------------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| Field          | Type             | Null | Key | Default           | Extra          |
+----------------+------------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| file_id        | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment |
| file_name      | varchar(255)     | NO   |     | NULL              |                |
| file_orig_name | varchar(255)     | NO   |     | NULL              |                |
| file_path      | varchar(255)     | NO   |     | NULL              |                |
| upload_date    | timestamp        | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |                |
 +----------------+------------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
```

What it is : Illegal string offset ? I have try [Illegal string offset Warning PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9869150/illegal-string-offset-warning-php) . But i still stuck.  Any help it so appreciated.

**Update**
This is my controller :

```
public function add_file_image($idx) {
    $last = $this->uri->total_segments();
    $id = rawurldecode($this->uri->segment($last));
    $pathToUpload = './assets/uploads/' . $id;

    if (!is_dir($pathToUpload)) {
        mkdir($pathToUpload, 0755, true);
    }
    $dir_exist = true; // flag for checking the directory exist or not
    if (!is_dir($pathToUpload)) {
        mkdir($pathToUpload, 0755, true);
        mkdir($pathToUpload . '/thumbs', 0755, true);
        $dir_exist = false; // dir not exist
    }

    if (!empty($_FILES)) {
        $config['upload_path'] = $pathToUpload;
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|';
        $config['file_name'] = $id;
        $config['overwrite'] = true;
        //$config['encrypt_name'] = TRUE;
        $this->load->library('upload');

        $files = $_FILES;
        $number_of_files = count($_FILES['file']['name']);
        $errors = 0;


        // codeigniter upload just support one fileto upload. so we need a litte trick
        for ($i = 0; $i < $number_of_files; $i++) {
            $_FILES['file']['name'] = $files['file']['name'][$i];
            $_FILES['file']['type'] = $files['file']['type'][$i];
            $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'] = $files['file']['tmp_name'][$i];
            $_FILES['file']['error'] = $files['file']['error'][$i];
            $_FILES['file']['size'] = $files['file']['size'][$i];
            // we have to initialize before upload

            $config['file_name'] = str_replace("_", " ", $id) . $i;

            // Execute upload
            $this->upload->initialize($config);

            if (!$this->upload->do_upload("file")) {
                $errors++;
                echo $this->upload->display_errors();
            } else {
                echo "<pre>";
                print_r($this->upload->data());

                //Insert to database
               $this->m_surveyor->save_files_info($this->upload->data());
            }
        }
        // Lakukan insert dengan menggunakan insert_batch.
        if ($errors > 0) {
            echo $errors . "File(s) cannot be uploaded";
        }
    } elseif ($this->input->post('file_to_remove')) {
        $file_to_remove = $this->input->post('file_to_remove');
        unlink("./assets/uploads/" . $file_to_remove);
    } else {
        $this->listFiles();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please, show how you invoke method save_files_info from the controller, together with upload processing code.

Answer (score 0):

The warning indicates that the array value is empty. Check for a value associated with the key before trying to assign it to some other variable.

This is one approach to checking that values are set.

```
foreach ($files as $file) {
   $file_data[] = array(
      "file_name" => isset($file['file_name']) ? $file['file_name']: "",
      "file_orig_name" => isset($file['orig_name']) ? $file['orig_name']: "",
      "file_path" => isset($file['full_path']) ? $file['full_path'] : "" );
```