# Illigal String Offset 'id' PHP

Tags: php, laravel-5

RESOLVED: I WAS ADDING EXTRA INDEX TO `$firms` LIKE `$firms['type'] = 'ABC'` AS `$firms` Already Contains CHILD ARRAYS. My BAD, Sorry.

**This might be duplicate** But i couldn't figure it out T _ T Sorry

As i am printing array results coming right from database, its continuously annoying me with error

```
Illegal string offset 'id'
```

When i simply **print_r** result array it gives me following result.

```
echo "<pre>";
   foreach ($firms as $firm) {
       print_r($firm[0]);
   }
echo "</pre>";
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [id] => 7923
    [rank] => 0
    [name] => CBRE
)
Array
(
    [id] => 7919
    [rank] => 0
    [name] => Aecom
)
```

But if i try to print 'id' it gives me error:

```
echo "<pre>";
    foreach ($firms as $firm) {
        echo $firm[0]['id'];
    }
echo "</pre>";
```

Error:

```
Illegal string offset 'id'
```

VAR_DUMP($firms) , Result:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    array(3) {
      ["id"]=>
      int(7923)
       ["rank"]=>
      int(0)
       ["name"]=>
       string(4) "CBRE"
   }
 }
 [1]=>
 array(1) {
   [0]=>
    array(3) {
      ["id"]=>
       int(7919)
       ["rank"]=>
       int(0)
       ["name"]=>
       string(5) "Aecom"
     }
  }
  [2]=>
   array(1) {
    [0]=>
     array(3) {
      ["id"]=>
      int(6793)
      ["rank"]=>
      int(1)
      ["name"]=>
      string(5) "AECOM"
   }
  }
}
```

Comment: can you try `echo $firm->id;`

Comment: Actually it didn't worked also, because i am getting results as array `$firms[] = Firm::whereId($favourite['firm_id'])->get()->toArray();`    It Gives Error `Trying to get property of non-object `

Comment: `echo $firm['id'];` ?

Comment: it won't work too, reason is-> When is `print_r($firms)` it display something like [This](http://imgur.com/a/YJ8Jk)

Comment: can you try removing the quotes of ['id'] so like this: $firm[0][id];

Comment: `Use of undefined constant id - assumed 'id'`  This is so annoying. i am working on PHP since 2012. but this is so out of box.

Comment: Well you said you tried `echo $firm[0]['id'];` but what about `echo $firm['0']['id'];` with quotes around `0`

Comment: it remains same, no difference :( Well Thanks

Comment: I don't think `$firm[0]` is actually an array. Please do a `var_dump($firms)` and add it to your question.

Comment: and/or find the last answer (from Kzquai) here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9869150/illegal-string-offset-warning-php?rq=1

Comment: Is it multidimensional array ??

Comment: IT must be like this 

Array ( [1] => Array ( [id] => 7923 [rank] => 0 [name] => Aecom ) [2] => Array ( [id] => 7919 [rank] => 0 [name] => CBRE ) )

Comment: I bet `$firm[0]` is a string. If you'd do `$firm[0][0]` you'll get "A".

Comment: Added `var_dump($firms)` to the question. Thanks @Jeff

Comment: yes it is @NavjotSingh

Comment: First used for loop like this and print the firm

 foreach ($firms as $firm) {
     print_r($firm);
    }