# Getting 'Illegal string offset' on simple array

Tags: php, arrays

I have simple array like

```
Array
(
    [vaucher] => 000000000000000001ea0e0e697ac203f2420d36c54ad7b2f16c5a3e0692a11b
    [addresses] => Array
    (
        [0] => address_1
        [1] => address_2
        [2] => address_3
    )

    [received] => 2017-01-03T06:49:28.593Z
     ...
)
```

and I'm trying to match address from `[addresses]` with address from my database but I've got `Illegal string offset 'addresses'`

Here is what I've trying to do

```
$match = false;

foreach ($total['addresses'] as $data) {
    if ($data == $order->address) {
            $match = $data;
            break;
    }
}
```

Why I've got illegal string offset here? 
I have tried with another array like on the provided SO thread and it's worked.. but this one doesn't work so it doesn't help me.

Comment: Does `var_dump($total);` give you the array you expect to see?

Comment: Yes, it's giving me what I've put on the question above.

Comment: Assuming none of the answers here helped? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9869150/illegal-string-offset-warning-php

Comment: give us phpfiddle link or there is nothing to have an issue

Comment: A shot into the dark: there is a mismatch of datatype of $match. In your first line you declared this variable as boolean and in the loop you tried to define it as array

Comment: @reporter  your shot seems correct

Comment: @reporter it can be like in the question with multiple addresses and I'm trying to loop over them and check if some of them match with the one from database. What is mean `mismatch of datatype`?

Comment: @VLS As I wrote: you give at first line `$match = false;`. It seems you give the variable `match` a boolean value. Within the loop you want to give `match`an Array or a String value `$match = $data`. A single equals sign is a keyword for declaration.

Comment: Is $data contain boolean value ?

Comment: @SoniVimal in my eyes not.

Comment: @reporter that is correct. Single `=` do the trick even I still can't understand why.. I want to match them i.e. to check if is exist.

Comment: @VLS And why don't you write `$match = true;`? You code says read the value from data -an element from array Address- and give this value the boolean variable `$match`.

Comment: I tough `$match = true;` meaning that will be true even if is false because it's true in the first place. Some misunderstanding here

Comment: can you post more of the source code? where does $total come from?

Comment: `$total` is curl which take json array from the url. Unfortunately I can't post the url here.