# How to solve an illegal string offset error during printing of array values?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I face this error

> **A PHP Error was encountered**
>
> Severity: Warning
>
> Message: Illegal string offset 'company'
>
> Filename: sales/print_file.php

**In my Controller**

```
$data=array("invoice_no"=>$invoice_no,
    "phone"=>$phone,
    "date"=>$date,
    "att"=>$Att,
    "company"=>$company,
    "area"=>$body,
    "subtotal"=>$subtotal,
    "tax"=>$tax,
    "total"=>$total,
    );

    .
    .
    $result=$this->other_tasks_model->inserts($data);
    .
    .
    $data["item1"] = $data;
    .
    .
    if($result==true)
        {
        $this->_tpl_super_admin('sales/print_file', $data);//for template changes based on user login
     }
     else{
     _error handling_
     }
```

**In my model**

```
public function inserts($data)
{
  $this->db->insert("invoice",$data);
  return $this->db->affected_rows() !=1 ? false:true;
}
```

**In my view**

```
  <?php 
    if(isset($item1)){
      foreach($item1 as $row){;
        echo "<h2>".$row['company']."</h2>";
        echo $row['date']."<br>"; 
        echo "#".$row['invoice_no'];
  ?>
```

Comment: what line is the error on exactly?

Comment: Can you paste the full error, with its line reference and let us know which line it refers to?

Comment: delete `foreach($item1 as $row){;` and change `$row` to `$item1`

Comment: `Message: Illegal string offset 'area'` where is this code in your view??????

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Illegal string offset Warning PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9869150/6521116)

Comment: Please show all your data here, there must be some code cause this issue you didn't show it here. Refer to this [Illegal string offset Warning PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9869150/6521116)

Comment: Try this - `$viewData["item1"] = $data;`
`$this->_tpl_super_admin('sales/print_file', $viewData);`

Comment: Sorry for the delay. here i have edited my question. @KrisRoofe
Mr.@DanWalker is this edit clears now?
What exactly I need to do is to Save the post values in db then display the post values in another view file(sales/print_file).

Comment: Can your show the $data in your controller and view?

Comment: @KrisRoofe The $data is initialised and assigning values in the controller as I typed above. $data=array("invoice_no"=>$invoice_no, ...
In view I can't use the $data variable directly like foreach($data as $row).

Comment: I mean pritn_r($data) to show the real value before and render the view.

Comment: Sorry the print_r($data) said Undefined Variable error.
but the print_r($item1) prints the values properly..@KrisRoofe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php 
  if(isset($item1)){
  foreach($item1 as $row){;
  echo "<h2>".$row['company']."</h2>";
  echo $row['date']."<br>"; 
  echo "#".$row['invoice_no'];
  ?>
```

as you have a 1 dimensional array

you do not require a foreach loop

either you do 2 thing

- Remove the foreach part

  or
- you modify $data being set to the view that way you can keep the
  foreach

loop

```
 $data[]= $data;(this will make it a 2 dimensional array)
$data["item1"] = $data;
.
```

Comment: the first option is the better option as you know the amount of data being passed

Comment: Thanks Mr.Reuben.

Comment: Kazz Already suggest this technique and it worked, anyway enjoy.