# WordPress Illegal string offset error

Tags: php, wordpress, post

I have a custom post type the I have built for a WordPress Site.  Everything functions as it should except when I add a new post, the custom meta fields are riddled with errors.

```
<br /><b>Warning</b>:  Illegal string offset 'Title' in <b>D:\Xampp\htdocs\wpexercise\wordpress\wp-content\themes\wpexercise\functions.php</b> on line <b>69</b><br />
```

I'm able to delete the error from the input field and input data and it saves,  but why is this error appearing.  Please help.

functions.php

```
function create_post_products_post() {
register_post_type( 'products_post',
    array(
        'labels'       => array(
            'name'       => __( 'Products' ),
        ),
        'public'       => true,
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'has_archive'  => true,
        'supports'     => array(
            'title',
            'editor',
            'excerpt',
            'thumbnail',
        ),
        'taxonomies'   => array(
            'post_tag',
            'category',
        )
    )
);
register_taxonomy_for_object_type( 'category', 'products_post' );
register_taxonomy_for_object_type( 'post_tag', 'products_post' );
}
add_action( 'init', 'create_post_products_post' );



function add_products_fields_meta_box() {
add_meta_box(
    'products_fields_meta_box', // $id
    'Product Fields', // $title
    'show_products_fields_meta_box', // $callback
    'products_post', // $screen
    'normal', // $context
    'high' // $priority
);
}
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'add_products_fields_meta_box' );

function show_products_fields_meta_box() {
global $post;
$meta = get_post_meta( $post->ID, $key='products_fields', true ); ?>

<input type="hidden" name="products_meta_box_nonce" value="<?php echo 
wp_create_nonce( basename(__FILE__) ); ?>">

<p>
    <label for="products_fields[Title]">Product Title</label>
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="products_fields[Title]" 
id="products_fields[textTitle]" class="regular-text" value="<?php echo 
$meta['Title']; ?>">
</p>

<p>
    <label for="products_fields[Link]">Product Link</label>
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="products_fields[Link]" id="products_fields[Link]" class="regular-text" value="<?php echo $meta['Link']; ?>">
</p>

<p>
    <label for="products_fields[bkgColor]">Background Color</label>
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="products_fields[bkgColor]" 
id="products_fields[bkgColor]" class="regular-text" value="<?php echo 
$meta['bkgColor']; ?>">
</p>

<p>
    <label for="products_fields[Image]">Product Image Path</label>
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="products_fields[Image]" 
id="products_fields[Image]" class="regular-text" value="<?php echo 
$meta['Image']; ?>">
</p>
```

Comment: which line is 69?

Comment: line 69 is
            <input type="text" name="products_fields[Title]" id="products_fields[textTitle]" class="regular-text" value="<?php echo $meta['Title']; ?>">

Comment: can you please `var_dump($meta);` and update your question with its output.

Comment: you could wrap that with isset. `<?php echo isset($meta['Title']) ? $meta['Title'] : ''; ?>`

Comment: basically `$meta` can't be an array if that is the error you're getting.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Illegal string offset Warning PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9869150/illegal-string-offset-warning-php)

Comment: Check the saving. Do you really have the data stored in the db? Looks like your `$meta` is a simple array with numeric indexes.

Comment: Kai Qing had the correct approach.  Thank you everyone for the swift turnaround time and helping me with this issue.  Works like a charm now

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Kai Qing here is the response that worked for me

```
<?php echo isset($meta['Title']) ? $meta['Title'] : ''; ?>
```