# I got the json data from the url and I need to print the json data in my laravel 5.6 view

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-4, laravel-5.1

Trying to print the json data in my laravel5.6 view using controller. I got an error

> Illegal string offset 'rates'

**My Controller Code**

```
 $req_url = 'https://v3.exchangerate-api.com/bulk/6eea6e74c3abe1df9de390c2/USD';
 $response_json = file_get_contents($req_url);
 $configdata4   = json_encode($response_json);
 $final_data4 = json_decode($configdata4,true);
 return view('clientlayout.main.registerdomain',compact('final_data4'));
```

**My view page Code**

```
@foreach($final_data4['rates'] as $value)
{{$value['USD']}}
@endforeach
```

Please suggest any solutions to this issue.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9869150/illegal-string-offset-warning-php) might be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your already get the response in json format, all you need to do is to decode and return it, as the following:

```
$req_url = 'https://v3.exchangerate-api.com/bulk/6eea6e74c3abe1df9de390c2/USD';
$response_json = file_get_contents($req_url);
$final_data4 = json_decode($response_json);
return view('clientlayout.main.registerdomain',compact('final_data4'));
```

Comment: add second param as `true` as OP uses as array here `json_decode($response_json,true)`

Answer (score 2):

No need to use `json_encode`. You are already getting as json format

```
 $req_url = 'https://v3.exchangerate-api.com/bulk/6eea6e74c3abe1df9de390c2/USD';
 $response_json = file_get_contents($req_url);
 $final_data4 = json_decode($response_json,true);
 return view('clientlayout.main.registerdomain',compact('final_data4'));
```

[Live Demo](https://eval.in/1006952)