# How to fix this `Illegal string offset` error in php?

Tags: php

I have a multidimensional array as below:

```
$rows[] = $row;
```

Now I want to create variable from looping this array. This is how I tried it:

```
foreach ($rows as $k => $value) {
  //echo '<pre>',print_r($value).'</pre>';
  $id    = $value['news_id'];
  $title = $value['news_title'];
  echo $title; 
}
```

But it produce an error as below:

> ......  Illegal string offset 'news_id'

This is the output of - `echo '<pre>',print_r($value).'</pre>';`

```
Array
(
    [news_id] => 1110
    [news_title] => test
    [news] => test des
)
1

Array
(
    [news_id] => 1109
    [news_title] => ශ්‍රී ලංකාවේ ප්‍රථම....
    [news] => දහසක් බාධක....
)
1
```

Can anybody tell me what is the wrong I have done?

**UPDATE**
output for `echo '<pre>',print_r($rows).'</pre>';`

```
Array
(
  [0] => 
  [1] => Array
      (
          [news_id] => 1110
          [news_title] => test
          [news] => test des
      )

  [2] => Array
      (
          [news_id] => 1109
          [news_title] => ශ්‍රී ලංකාවේ ප්‍රථම....
          [news] => දහසක් බාධක....        
      )

)
1
```

Comment: @BilalAhmed we can use that comma for it.

Comment: @BilalAhmed Does not matter at all.

Comment: Please add this to your code and put the result here:  `echo "<pre>" . print_r($rows) . "</pre>";`  Because your syntax (`array['index']`) works for me.  I would like to see how $rows is created.

Comment: @Nic3500 I updated question

Comment: Ok thanks.  So `$rows[0]['news_id']` does not exist.  Add a check `if (isset($value['news_id'])) { ... }`

Comment: Your problem is that array element 0 doesn't contain a record in the format you're expecting.  Either make sure the array is only populated with records in the expected format, or add some kind of check into your loop (eg ```if (empty($value)) {continue;}```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Illegal string offset Warning PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9869150/illegal-string-offset-warning-php)

Comment: Weird.  I just tried with both PHP 5.6.30 and 7.2.10.  I setup a test with your `$rows` and your `foreach` code, no modifications.  Well I got no errors.  For `$rows[0]` it just prints nothing, and moves on.  No errors, no logs, nothing ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `isset` function because your 0 index is empty in `$row`

```
foreach ($rows as $k => $value) {
  if(isset($value['news_id'])){
    $id    = $value['news_id'];
    $title = $value['news_title'];
    echo $title; 
  }

}
```

you should add check (condition) when you assign data to `$rows`

Comment: The error `Illegal string offset 'news_id'` tells that $value is a string and `'news_id'` is an illegal index, this *may* suppress error but not explaining what is wrong or how to fix it.

Comment: 0th index doesn't need to be empty, simply being a string instead of an array would suffice.  Let `$rows = array('key' => array('news_id' => 'foo', 'news_title' => 'bar'), 'key1' => array('news_id' => 'foo', 'news_title' => 'bar'), 'key2' => array('news_id' => 'foo', 'news_title' => 'bar'), 'key3' => 'I am a simple string') `, then trraversing this array with a foreach loop and checking `$value['news_title']` will simply fail with `Illegal string offset 'news_id'` .