# How to $POST data to a $_SESSION array

Tags: php

I am getting all types of errors on the following code.  I want to post data from my form and store in a $_SESSION array for future processing

> Illegal string offset 'SurveyDate'
>      Illegal string offset 'Income'

```
<input class="formFields" type="date" id="txtDateOfSurvey" name="mycensus[0][SurveyDate]"
<input class="formFields" type="numeric" id="txtIncome" name="mycensus[0][Income]"

<?php
    session_start();

    if( !isset($_SESSION['mycart2']))
    {
        $_SESSION['mycart2'] = array();
    }
    $_SESSION['mycart2'] = array_merge($_SESSION['mycart'], $_POST['mycensus']);


    foreach($_SESSION['mycart2'] as $v)
    {
        echo $v['SurveyDate'] . ' was born on ' . $v['Income'] . '<br>';
    }

?>
```

I want the array mycart2 to contain all the entries that I enter on my form.

Comment: Dump `$_SESSION['mycart2']` and see what the output looks like. It looks as though it is returning a string and therefore `$v` is each letter within the string.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Illegal string offset Warning PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9869150/illegal-string-offset-warning-php)

Comment: the array_merge seems a bit pointless .. why not just set `$_SESSION['mycart2']` to equal `$_POST['mycensus']`?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
  session_start();
  if(is_array(mycensus)){
    $survey_date = mycensus[0]['SurveyDate'];
   $Income = mycensus[0]['Income'];
}
  ?>

<input class="formFields" type="date" id="txtDateOfSurvey" name="survey_date" value="<?php echo $survey_date; ?>">
<input class="formFields" type="numeric" id="txtIncome" name="income" value="<?php echo $Income; ?>">
<?Php


    if( !isset($_SESSION['mycart2']))
    {
        $_SESSION['mycart2'] = array();
    }
    $_SESSION['mycart2'] = array_merge($_SESSION['mycart'], $_POST['mycensus']);


    foreach($_SESSION['mycart2'] as $v)
    {
        echo $v['SurveyDate'] . ' was born on ' . $v['Income'] . '<br>';
    }

?>
```