# PHP Warning: Illegal string offset 'text'

Tags: php, mysql, button

I keep getting the following error in PHP:

> [13-Jul-2019 06:49:43 UTC] PHP Warning:  Illegal string offset 'text'
>   in
>   /home/catchandreport/public_html/sweettune.info/LikeDislike/index.php
>   on line 15

Is there any way that I can replace my string with something else?

I haven't tried anything yet. While I'm at it, this is a totally different problem, but in another line of code I get

> Illegal string offset 'id'

Is there something I'm doing wrong that I can change?

```
  <?php echo $post['text']; ?>
  <div class="post-info">
    <!-- if user likes post, style button differently -->
    <i <?php if (userLiked($post['id'])): ?>
          class="fa fa-thumbs-up like-btn"
      <?php else: ?>
          class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up like-btn"
      <?php endif ?>
      data-id="<?php echo $post['id'] ?>"><img src="catlogo.ico"></i>
    <span class="likes"><?php echo getLikes($post['id']); ?></span>
```

Comment: Where are the values for `$post` coming from?

Comment: @NigelRen  <?php foreach ($posts as $post): ?> Thats all I have associated with $posts, theres nothing else.

Comment: You may find you don't need the `foreach()` and it may be worth trying to use your `$posts` variable instead - `$posts['text']`

Comment: Did you mean `$_POST`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this error mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Illegal string offset Warning PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9869150/illegal-string-offset-warning-php)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the value $post["text"] isnt set in your array.

If you are not sure that the array section/key you are using exist, you should always test for it first:

```
$textVar = (isset($post["text"]) ? $post["text"] : "YOUR ALTERNATE VALUE");
```

Maybe even check if your array is set:

```
$post = (is_array($post) ? $post : array());
```

If you cant get the correct value, then try to var_dump your array to see the type and content:

```
var_dump($post);
```

Hope it helps

Comment: as @JureW metioned, using "array_key_exists" might be a better idea since "isset" will return FALSE if your array value is NULL.

Please let us know if this solved your problem

Answer (score 0):

Illegal string offset warning will come when the variable type is not array and you're trying to access the array key value.

Let me give you an example (Wrong Way);

```
$post = ''; // Initialized as empty string
$post['text'] = 'abc'; // It will work but give you illegal offset value

echo $post['text']; // It will work but give you illegal offset value
```

Example of doing in correct way:

```
$post = array(); // Initialied as array
$post['text'] = 'abc';  // Now it will not give the illegal offset value

echo $post['text']; // Now it will not give illegal offset value
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a problem with illegal string offset, first, as @SeeQue already mentioned,

Test if post is an array, than test for keys, not if they are set, but if they are there:

```
                if(is_array($post)) {
                   if(array_key_exists("text", $post)) {
                    //do something
                  }
                }
```

Maybe this could help.

BR