# How fix the "llegal string offset" while uploading excel file into database

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to import an Excel file into my table using the **MaatWebsite package**. But every time I get errors like these:

> Illegal string offset 'Emp'

I am following this [tutorial](https://www.webslesson.info/2019/02/import-excel-file-in-laravel.html). And here is the code I have tried:

```php
 $path = $request->file('attendance_data')->getRealPath();

 $data = Excel::load($path)->get();

 if($data->count() > 0)
 {
     foreach($data->toArray() as $key => $value)
     {
         foreach($value as $row)
         {
             $insert_data[] = array(
                 'employee_card'  => $row['Emp'],
                 'attendance_date'   => $row['Date'],
                 'attendance_time'    => $row['On'],
             );
         }
     }

     if(!empty($insert_data))
     {
         DB::table('attendance_logs')->insert($insert_data);
     }
```

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment so I've posted this as an answer.

Have you tried to die and dump the `$row` to check that it is an array of `key => value` pairs as you're expecting? The error looks to show up when trying to access a key of an array with numeric keys. This could also happen if `$row` is a string, as you can access string characters using a numeric index similar to an array.

```php
$path = $request->file('attendance_data')->getRealPath();

$data = Excel::load($path)->get();

if($data->count() > 0) {

  foreach ($data->toArray() as $key => $value) {

    foreach ($value as $row) {

      // Print the data of $row to see what it actually is
      // and kill the process
      dd($row);

      $insert_data[] = array(
        'employee_card' => $row['Emp'],
        'attendance_date' => $row['Date'],
        'attendance_time' => $row['On'],
      );

    }

  }

  if (!empty($insert_data)) {

    DB::table('attendance_logs')->insert($insert_data);

  }

}
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28610049/12446017) looks to be related.

Comment: It is better to provide the code snippet for better understanding because an explanation could lead to confusion at times.