# Illegal string offset 'name' and Uninitialized string offset: 0

Tags: php

Could you please this fix di problem?
[image: Provided Code Image]

```
Warning: Illegal string offset 'name' in C:\xampp\htdocs\frm\modules\controllers\lspengirimanController.php on line 54

Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 0 in C:\xampp\htdocs\frm\modules\controllers\lspengirimanController.php on line 54

Warning: Illegal string offset 'name' in C:\xampp\htdocs\frm\modules\controllers\lspengirimanController.php on line 56

Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 0 in C:\xampp\htdocs\frm\modules\controllers\lspengirimanController.php on line 56
```

Comment: Please go read [ask]. Code relevant to your problem belongs directly into your question, in text form and properly formatted - do not show images of code instead. Also, please research these error messages, they have been discussed before.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Illegal string offset Warning PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9869150/illegal-string-offset-warning-php)