# I keep getting `Illegal string offset` in my php code, how do I fix this?

Tags: php

I keep getting the error above when checking out. The code is used for an app where the buyer makes a purchase. The purchase is successful but the error pops up during the check out process. In particular it says: "Warning: illegal offset 'OrderSession' on line 7" 
OrderSession is the name of my PHP file.

Line 7 is --> $Order_Data=$Order_Data['msg']['OrderSession']['string'];

```
<?php
    include('config.php');
    //print_r($_POST);

    //echo $Order_Data=@$_POST;
    //$Order_Data=key(@$_POST);
     $Order_Data=$Order_Data['msg']['OrderSession']['string'];

    //if app data recive store into session for use it later
    if(isset($_GET['id']))
    {
        $_SESSION['App_Data']=$Order_Data;
    }

    //$json_data=base64_decode($json_data); 
    $App_Data=$_SESSION['App_Data'];
    if($App_Data=="")
    {
        echo"access denied";
        die();
    }

    //covert base64 to normal json from session App_Data
    $json_data=base64_decode($App_Data); 

    //convert normal json into array
    $order_data=json_decode($json_data, true);

    $total_price=$order_data['price'];

    if (isset($_GET['payment'])) 
    {
        //print_r($_POST);
        if ($_GET['payment'] == 'paypal') 
        {

            try 
            {
                // login with paypal module
                $payer = new \PayPal\Api\Payer();
                $payer->setPaymentMethod('paypal');

                $amount = new \PayPal\Api\Amount();
                $amount->setTotal($total_price);
                $amount->setCurrency(PAYPAL_CURRENCY);

                $transaction = new \PayPal\Api\Transaction();
                $transaction->setAmount($amount);

                $redirectUrls = new \PayPal\Api\RedirectUrls();
                $redirectUrls->setReturnUrl(SET_RETURN_URL)
                    ->setCancelUrl(SET_CANCEL_URL);

                $payment = new \PayPal\Api\Payment();
                $payment->setIntent('sale')
                    ->setPayer($payer)
                    ->setTransactions(array($transaction))
                    ->setRedirectUrls($redirectUrls);


                $payment->create($apiContext);
                // login with paypal module

                echo "<script>window.location='".$payment->getApprovalLink() ."'</script>";



            } 
            catch (\PayPal\Exception\PayPalConnectionException $ex) 
            {
                // This will print the detailed information on the exception.
                //REALLY HELPFUL FOR DEBUGGING
                echo $ex->getData();
            }
        }
    }


    $url=BASE_URL.'api/showUserDetail';
    $data =array(
        "user_id" => $order_data['user_id'],
        "restaurant_id" => $order_data['restaurant_id']    
    );
    $user_data=@curl_request($data,$url);

    // print_r($user_data);
    $user_cards=$user_data['msg']['UserInfo']['Cards'];
    $restaurantName=$user_data['msg']['Restaurant']['Restaurant']['name'];
    $restaurantImage=$user_data['msg']['Restaurant']['Restaurant']['image'];
    $currency_symbol=$user_data['msg']['Restaurant']['Currency']['symbol'];
    $tax=$user_data['msg']['Restaurant']['Tax']['tax'];

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">


    <title>Payment | Checkout</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale = 1.0, maximum-scale = 1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <link href="assets/css/fonts.css" rel="stylesheet"> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/style.css?time<?php echo time(); ?>">
    <!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">-->
    <script src="assets/js/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script>
       $(window).load(function() {
         $('#status').fadeOut();
         $('#preloader').delay(350).fadeOut('slow');
         $('body').delay(350).css({'overflow':'visible'});
       })
    </script>

</head>
<body>


<div id="preloader" align="center">
  <div id="loading">
    <div class="spinner loading"></div>
  </div>
</div>


    <div class="mainServicesDetail">

            <?php

                //paypal thank you page
                if(isset($_GET['status']))
                {

                    ?>
                        <br><br>
                        <div class="container">
                            <div class="restaurantInfo" style="text-align: center;">
                                <img src="assets/images/done.png" style="width: 80px;">
                                <h2 style="margin: 10px 0px;font-weight: 600;font-size: 18px; color:#363B3F;">Thank You</h2>
                                <p>Your Payment is Successfully Done</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                   <?php
                   die();
                }
                else
                if(isset($_GET['paymentId']) && isset($_GET['token']) && isset($_GET['PayerID']))
                {

                        $paymentId=$_GET['paymentId'];

                        $App_Data;
                        //covert base64 to normal json from session App_Data
                        $json_data=base64_decode($App_Data); 

                        //convert normal json into array
                        $json_app_date=json_decode($json_data, true);
                        // print_r($json_app_date);

                        //modify json_array
                        $transaction_obj=array(
                                                "cod"=>"0",
                                                "payment_id"=>"0",
                                                "transaction"=> array
                                                (
                                                     "value"=>$paymentId,
                                                    "type"=>"paypal"
                                                )
                                            );
                        $newArrayPost=array_replace($json_app_date,$transaction_obj);

                        // post data on service
                        $url=BASE_URL.'api/placeOrder';
                        $data =$newArrayPost;
                        //echo json_encode($data);
                        $result_data=@curl_request($data,$url);

                        if($result_data['code']=="200")
                        {
                           echo "<script>window.location='./?status=paymentSuccess'</script>";
                        }

                       ?>

                       <?php
                      die();
                }
                else
                if(isset($_GET['payment']) || isset($_GET['p']))
                {   
                    if(@$_GET['payment'] == 'cards')
                    {


                        ?>
                            <style>
                                .singleCard
                                {
                                    padding: 10px 0 10px 10px;
                                    border: solid 1px #eee;
                                    margin: 8px 0 0 0;
                                    border-radius: 4px;
                                    color: #575757;
                                    font-size: 14px;
                                    cursor: pointer;
                                }
                                .cards
                                {
                                    margin: 0 20px 0 20px;
                                }

                                .singleCard img
                                {
                                    width: 40px;
                                    vertical-align: middle;
                                    margin-right: 10px;
                                }
                            </style>
                            <br><br>

                            <div class="container">
                                    <div class="mainSecureCheckout">
                                        <div class="sectionHeading padding20">
                                            <h3>secure checkout</h3>
                                        </div>
                                        <hr>
                                        <div class="paymentMethod">
                                            <h3 class="padding20">Payment Method</h3>
                                            <div class="itsSafeToPay padding20">
                                                <i class="fa fa-lock" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                                <p style="color:#797A7E;font-weight: 300;font-size: 13px;"> 
                                                    It's safe to pay. All transactions are protected by SSL encryption. 
                                                </p>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="pamentTypes" style="margin-top: 10px;">
                                                <form id="formvisa" action="index.php?payment=payCardNow" method="get">
                                                    <input type="hidden" name="payment" value="payCardNow">
                                                    <div class="cards">
                                                        <?php
                                                          //print_r($_SESSION);
                                                          //  echo $user_cards;
                                                            if($user_cards!="")
                                                            {
                                                                foreach ($user_cards as $single_row):
                                                                    ?>
                                                                        <div class="singleCard" onclick="selectPayment('<?php echo $single_row['PaymentMethod']['id']; ?>')">
                                                                            <input type="radio" id="<?php echo $single_row['PaymentMethod']['id']; ?>" name="selectCard" value="<?php echo $single_row['PaymentMethod']['id']; ?>" required>
                                                                            <img src="assets/images/<?php echo $single_row['brand'] ?>.jpg">
                                                                            **** **** **** <?php echo $single_row['last4'] ?>
                                                                        </div>
                                                                    <?php
                                                                endforeach;
                                                            }
                                                        ?>
                                                        <a href="index.php?p=addNewCard" style="text-decoration: none; border: 0px;">
                                                            <div class="singleCard">
                                                                + Add New Card
                                                            </div>
                                                        </a>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <button type="submit" class="proceedBtn">
                                                        Continue
                                                    </button>
                                                </form>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        </form>
                                    </div>

                            </div>

                       <?php 

                    }
                    else
                    if($_GET['payment'] == 'payCardNow')
                    {

                        $selectCard=@$_GET['selectCard'];
                        if(@$_GET['selectCard']=="")
                        {
                            echo "<script>window.location='index.php?payment=cards&status=error'</script>";
                        }

                        $App_Data;
                        //covert base64 to normal json from session App_Data
                        $json_data=base64_decode($App_Data); 

                        //convert normal json into array
                        $json_app_date=json_decode($json_data, true);
                        // print_r($json_app_date);

                        //modify json_array
                        $transaction_obj=array(
                                                "cod"=>"0",
                                                "payment_id"=>$selectCard,
                                                "transaction"=> array
                                                (
                                                    "value"=>"1",
                                                    "type"=>"stripe"
                                                )
                                            );
                        $newArrayPost=array_replace($json_app_date,$transaction_obj);

                        // post data on service
                        $url=BASE_URL.'api/placeOrder';
                        $data =$newArrayPost;
                        //echo json_encode($data);
                        $result_data=@curl_request($data,$url);

                        if($result_data['code']=="200")
                        {
                           echo "<script>window.location='./?status=paymentSuccess'</script>";
                        }

                    }
                    else
                    if($_GET['p'] == 'addNewCard')
                    {
                        ?>
                            <style>
                                .singlefield
                                {
                                    border: solid 1px #eee;
                                    margin: 8px 0 0 0;
                                    border-radius: 4px;
                                    height: 38px;
                                    padding: 3px;

                                }
                                .formField
                                {
                                    margin: 0 20px 0 20px;
                                }

                                .singlefield input
                                {
                                    width: 290px;
                                    height: 35px;
                                    padding-left: 5px;
                                    color: #575757;
                                    font-size: 13px;
                                    font-weight: 400;
                                    border: none;
                                    outline: 0;
                                }


                            </style>
                            <br><br>

                            <div class="container">
                                    <div class="mainSecureCheckout">
                                        <div class="sectionHeading padding20">
                                            <h3>Add New Card</h3>
                                            <img src="assets/images/cards.png" style="width: 180px;margin-top: 10px;">
                                        </div>
                                        <hr>


                                                    <div class="singlefield">
                                                        <input type="number" name="cvv_number" id="cvv_number" placeholder="CVV">
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                                <button type="button" name="submit" class="proceedBtn" onclick="addCard()">
                                                    Continue
                                                </button>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                            </div>

                       <?php  
                    }
                    else
                    if($_GET['payment'] == 'cod')
                    {
                        $App_Data;
                        //covert base64 to normal json from session App_Data
                        $json_data=base64_decode($App_Data); 

                        //convert normal json into array
                        $json_app_date=json_decode($json_data, true);
                        // print_r($json_app_date);

                        //modify json_array
                        $transaction_obj=array(
                                                "cod"=>"1",
                                                "payment_id"=>"0",
                                                "transaction"=> array
                                                (
                                                     "value"=>"1",
                                                    "type"=>"cod"
                                                )
                                            );
                        $newArrayPost=array_replace($json_app_date,$transaction_obj);

                        // post data on service
                        $url=BASE_URL.'api/placeOrder';
                        $data =$newArrayPost;
                        //echo json_encode($data);
                        $result_data=@curl_request($data,$url);

                        if($result_data['code']=="200")
                        {
                           echo "<script>window.location='./?status=paymentSuccess'</script>";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            echo "<script>window.location='./?status=paymentFaild'</script>";
                        }

                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    ?>


                            <div class="container">    
                                <div class="serviceDetails">
                                    <div class="restaurantInfo" style="text-align: center;">
                                        <div style="background: url('<?php echo BASE_URL.$restaurantImage; ?>') , grey;margin-left:35%;height: 80px;width: 80px;background-repeat: no-repeat;border-radius: 50%;background-size: cover;background-position: center;"></div>
                                        <h2 style="margin: 10px 0px;font-weight: 500;font-size: 18px; color:#363B3F;"><?php echo $restaurantName; ?></h2>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="detailOption">
                                        <hr>
                                        <p style="color: #6E6F74;font-size: 14px;font-weight: 300;">Services Detail</p>
                                        <div class="options">
                                            <ul>
                                                <li><span>Rider Tip</span></li>
                                                <li><span>Sub total</span></li>
                                                <li><span>Tax (<?php echo $tax; ?>%)</span></li>
                                                <li><span>Discount (0%)</span></li>
                                                <li><span>Delivery Fee</span></li>
                                            </ul>
                                            <ul class="textRight">
                                                <li><span><?php echo $currency_symbol.$order_data['rider_tip']; ?></span></li>
                                                <li><span><?php echo $currency_symbol.$order_data['sub_total']; ?></span></li>
                                                <li><span><?php echo $currency_symbol.$order_data['tax']; ?></span></li>
                                                <li><span>&nbsp;</span></li>
                                                <li><span><?php echo $currency_symbol.$order_data['delivery_fee']; ?></span></li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </div>
                                        <hr>
                                        <div class="total">
                                            <ul>
                                                <li><span>total</span></li>
                                                <li class="dollar textRight "><span><?php echo $currency_symbol.$order_data['price']; ?></span></li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <style>

                               body
                               {
                                   -webkit-user-select: none; /* Safari */
                                  -ms-user-select: none; /* IE 10+ and Edge */
                                  user-select: none; /* Standard syntax */
                               }

                            </style>
                            <div class="container">
                                    <div class="mainSecureCheckout">
                                        <div class="sectionHeading padding20">
                                            <h3>secure checkout</h3>
                                        </div>
                                        <hr>
                                        <form id="formvisa" action="index.php?action=payNow" method="get">
                                            <div class="paymentMethod">
                                            <h3 class="padding20">Payment Method</h3>
                                            <div class="itsSafeToPay padding20">
                                                <i class="fa fa-lock" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                                <p style="color:#797A7E;font-weight: 300;font-size: 13px;"> 
                                                    It's safe to pay. All transactions are protected by SSL encryption. 
                                                </p>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="pamentTypes" style="margin-top: 10px;">

                                                <div class="choseOption" onclick="selectPayment('cod');">
                                                    <input type="radio" id="cod" name="payment" value="cod" style="border: 0px; text-decoration: none;" checked>
                                                    <img src="assets/images/cod.png">
                                                </div>

                                                <div class="choseOption" onclick="selectPayment('cards');">
                                                    <input type="radio" id="cards" name="payment" value="cards">
                                                    <img src="assets/images/cards.png">
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="choseOption" onclick="selectPayment('paypal');">
                                                    <input type="radio" id="paypal" name="payment" value="paypal">
                                                    <img src="assets/images/paypal.png">
                                                </div>



                                                <button type="submit" class="proceedBtn" onclick="showLoading()">
                                                    Continue
                                                </button>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        </form>
                                    </div>

                            </div>
                    <?php
                }



            ?>



    </div>

    <script>

        function showLoading()
        {
            $('#preloader').fadeIn();
        }

        function selectPayment(payment_method)
        {
            document.getElementById(payment_method).checked = true;
        }

        function addCard()
        {

            document.getElementById("preloader").style.display = "block";
            var full_name=document.getElementById("full_name").value;
            var car_number=document.getElementById("car_number").value;
            var month=document.getElementById("month").value;
            var year=document.getElementById("year").value;
            var cvv_number=document.getElementById("cvv_number").value;

            if(full_name=="" || car_number=="" || month=="" || year=="" || cvv_number=="")
            {
                document.getElementById("preloader").style.display = "none";
                alert("Information must be filled");
                return false;    
            }

            var xmlhttp;
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            } else {// code for IE6, IE5
                xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () 
            {
                if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) 
                {
                    //alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
                    //document.getElementById('contentReceived').innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
                    if(xmlhttp.responseText=="200")
                    {
                        document.getElementById("preloader").style.display = "block";
                        window.location='index.php?payment=cards';
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
                        if(xmlhttp.responseText)
                        {
                            window.location='./?payment=cards';
                            document.getElementById("preloader").style.display = "none";
                        }

                    }

                }
            }
            xmlhttp.open("GET", "ajex-event.php?q=addNewCard&full_name="+full_name+"&car_number="+car_number+"&month="+month+"&year="+year+"&cvv_number="+cvv_number);
            xmlhttp.send();
        }
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think you are looking at the wrong file

Comment: Please provide the complete Error Message.

Comment: @HarishST the error is shown in the IOS app when checking out. It directly displays: **"warning: illegal string offset 'OrderSession' in /home/aaron/public_html/myapp     on line 7"**

Comment: Actually, `warning: illegal string offset` means that you are trying to access a key which is not avaialble. Check where you used `OrderSession`, print the variable before that and check the variable have that key.

Comment: Consider: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9869150/illegal-string-offset-warning-php

Comment: @JohnConde I think you are right! i just updated my post with the correct file.