# Foreach loop giving me this error "Warning: Illegal string offset"

Tags: php, foreach

I'm trying to print all the rows from my table I used if statement but it only return one row, so I tried to use foreach statement but it gives me an error "Warning: Illegal string offset" for each row, this is the code I'm using:

```
$sql = "SELECT date, km_entre, km_sortie, type, montant FROM carburant WHERE id_user = 0";
$statement = $conn->query($sql);
$res = $statement->fetch();

foreach ($res as $roww){
    echo ' <tr>
    <td>' .$roww['date']. '</td>
    <td>' .$roww['km_entre']. '</td>
    <td>' .$roww['km_sortie']. '</td>
    <td>' .$roww['type']. '</td>
    <td>' .$roww['montant']. '</td>

    </tr>';
 }
```

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: `id_user = 0` I guess only 1 user has id 0

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9869150/illegal-string-offset-warning-php

Comment: i set id_user to 0 by default so all the entries has id_user 0.

Comment: i checked your suggested article and i found what i was missing, the trick is to change fetch to fetchALL. thank you Arif Khan for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for everyone having the same problem check this :
[Illegal string offset Warning PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9869150/illegal-string-offset-warning-php)
all i had to do is changing fetch() to fetchALL(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC).